# Query MongoDB for single field and insert into array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm currently use Mongoid to talk to my mongodb database. I have a query like the following:

```
ClassDoc.only(:class_id).where(:recurrs => true)
```

I'm only interested in the IDs as I exclude them in a subsequent query. However, the subsequent query needs the IDs in an array so I have to do this:

```
first_result_ids = ClassDoc.only(:class_id).where(:recurrs => true).collect { |class| class.class_id }
```

This takes quite a long time since AFAIK 'collect' loops over every result. It can take up to 10s to loop over just 1000 results.

Is there a way to pull the IDs out directly into an array?

Comment: If you only need class_id i would try to use an covered indexe for that query, so the result will come from the index only. this will speed up the queries a lot. see: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#measuring-index-use  it may work with .only() in mongoid

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
first_result_ids = ClassDoc.only(:class_id).where(:recurrs => true).map(&:class_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the try but no (or negligible) time difference between the two.